# How do I show multiple IPs via a label in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, network-programming

I am very new to programming in general, so the answer may be a very simple one.  I am trying to display all IPs from each NIC, into a label.  I can run the same code into Console and make it string out correctly.  I can add it to a listbox and display it correctly but I cant figure out how to get more than just One IP into the Label.  Hope that makes sense. I found the majority of this code on the internet and trying to see how it all works together, so if you see some commented lines that might not make sense, you know why. The label in question is label8.Text

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //first we should create an array of the network interfaces
            NetworkInterface[] nics = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

            //now lets iterate through the list of nics and call them adapter
            foreach (NetworkInterface adapter in nics)
            {
                //add the adapter description to the listbox1 items
                listBox1.Items.Add(adapter.Description);
            }
        }

        public void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Lets make our form taller so that the labels can be seen.
            Form1.ActiveForm.Height = 320;

            //Get the currently chosen listBox item.
            string nicname = listBox1.Text;

            //Again build an array of all the Network Interfaces.
            NetworkInterface[] nics = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

            //Lets loop through those interfaces
            foreach (NetworkInterface adapter in nics)
            {
                //Lets condition on the adapter description making sure it equals the nicname of the chosen adapter in the listbox1
                if (nicname == adapter.Description)
                {
                    //Lets update all the labels to display more information about the chosen adapter.
                    label1.Text = adapter.Description;
                    label2.Text = "Name: " + adapter.Name;
                    label3.Text = "Type: " + adapter.NetworkInterfaceType;
                    label4.Text = "Status: " + adapter.OperationalStatus;
                    label5.Text = "Speed: " + adapter.Speed;
                    label6.Text = "Multicast Support? " + adapter.SupportsMulticast;
                    label7.Text = "MAC: " + adapter.GetPhysicalAddress();

                    //NetworkInterface[] prop = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
                    IPInterfaceProperties properties = adapter.GetIPProperties();

                    foreach (IPAddressInformation uniCast in properties.UnicastAddresses)
                    {
                        label8.Text = "IP: " + (uniCast.Address); 
                        //label11.Text = "IP: " +  uniCast.Address; 
                        //listBox2.Items.Add(uniCast.Address);
                        foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation uipi in adapter.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
                        label10.Text = "Subnet: " + uipi.IPv4Mask;
                    }
                    foreach (GatewayIPAddressInformation GateWay in properties.GatewayAddresses)
                    {
                        label9.Text = "Gateway: " + GateWay.Address;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you are resetting the label here:

```
label8.Text = "IP: " + (uniCast.Address);
```

you can change it to:

```
label8.Text += (uniCast.Address);
```

or

```
label8.Text = label8.Text + (uniCast.Address);
```

then you just have to put:

```
label8.Text = "IP: ";
```

before the loop to put the prefix of IP on it.

Lazy version:

```
if (nicname == adapter.Description)
{
    //Lets update all the labels to display more information about the chosen adapter.
    label1.Text = adapter.Description;
    label2.Text = "Name: " + adapter.Name;
    label3.Text = "Type: " + adapter.NetworkInterfaceType;
    label4.Text = "Status: " + adapter.OperationalStatus;
    label5.Text = "Speed: " + adapter.Speed;
    label6.Text = "Multicast Support? " + adapter.SupportsMulticast;
    label7.Text = "MAC: " + adapter.GetPhysicalAddress();
    label8.Text = "IP: ";

    //NetworkInterface[] prop = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
    IPInterfaceProperties properties = adapter.GetIPProperties();

    foreach (IPAddressInformation uniCast in properties.UnicastAddresses)
    {
        label8.Text += (uniCast.Address); 
        label10.Text = "Subnet: ";

        foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation uipi in adapter.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
        label10.Text += uipi.IPv4Mask;
    }
    foreach (GatewayIPAddressInformation GateWay in properties.GatewayAddresses)
    {
        label9.Text = "Gateway: " + GateWay.Address;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you do this in the foreach:

```
label8.Text = "IP: " + (uniCast.Address);
```

You're overriding your pervious text.

Either use `+=` to concatenate, or build it with a string builder, and then use that for your label.